# Find previous date in cakephp?

Tags: php, sql, database, cakephp, find

I hava a table with 'date' column. Dates are ordered. I have a date and I must find the record with it. But if there isn't the exact date, I must find the nearest previous record. How can I do it?

I'm using php with cakephp framework and I know find 'first' and the others functions, but I don't know which I can use.

Thanks!

Comment: You question is pretty superficial. You don't know about less-than-or-equal conditions? You don't know how to limit selects? What exactly is it that you are having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it as bellow

```
$days = '-7 days'; // prev a week
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$prevDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($days, strtotime($today)));
$conditions = array('YourModel.colDate >=' => $prevDate, 'YourModel.colDate <=' => $today);
// find all records have $prevDate <= colDate <= $today
$this->YourModel->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```

Answer (score -3):

Here are some statements that should help you on your way.

```
create table dates
(birthday date   primary key);


insert into dates
values 
    (DATE '2015-12-15'),
    (DATE '2015-11-14'),
    (DATE '2015-10-13');

select birthday,
       to_date('20/12/2015 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
       datediff(to_date('20/12/2015 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), birthday)  
from dates
order by 3
```

Comment: Hey, dropping links related to your application like this is pretty spammy. Don't do that!